# Failed to apply plugin 'com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, groovy

Currently working on a gradle project am not familiar with gradle so it's a learning curve.

am encountering below error which seems to be clear but confusing me.

`Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/eclipse/jgit/api/errors/JGitInternalException has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0`

I have Java 8 installed in my PC and below is my gradle.build file

```
1   ext {
2       springBootVersion = '2.2.11.RELEASE'
3   }
4   repositories {
5       mavenCentral()
6       maven {
7           url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
8       }
9   }
10  dependencies {
11      classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
12      classpath 'org.junit.platform:junit-platform-gradle-plugin:1.0.0-RC3'
13      classpath "gradle.plugin.com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties:gradle-git-properties:2.2.4" //TODO investigate
14      classpath "com.diffplug.spotless:spotless-plugin-gradle:5.12.5"
15  }
16}
17
18 apply plugin: 'java'
19 apply plugin: 'idea'
20 apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
21 apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
22 apply plugin: 'war'
23 apply plugin: 'org.junit.platform.gradle.plugin'
24 apply plugin: 'com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties' // TODO investigate
25 apply plugin: 'com.diffplug.spotless'
26
27 group = 'io.sndk7'
28 version = '0.0.1'
29 sourceCompatibility = 1.8

it's failing on line number 24 while trying to apply the plugin which is added as a dependence on line 13
```

Answer (score 1):

The git plugin you're using relies on jgit

Jgit has moved to be Java 11+ so won't work on Java 8

https://github.com/n0mer/gradle-git-properties/issues/195

Shows workarounds to get it to work on Java 8

Or... You could migrate your project to Java 11+

Comment: Tim, is this something you can help with -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73541172/com-gorylenko-generategitpropertiestask-property-gitproperties-is-missing-an