# 'com.gorylenko.GenerateGitPropertiesTask' property 'gitProperties' is missing an input or output annotation?

Tags: git, gradle, intellij-idea, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I am facing below error. I have no idea which plugin is causing this.
I am using `Java 11` and the `Gradle 7.4.1` wrapper

> Some problems were found with the configuration of task
> ':myservice-server:generateGitProperties' (type
> 'GenerateGitPropertiesTask').
>
> - In plugin 'com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties' type 'com.gorylenko.GenerateGitPropertiesTask' property 'gitProperties' is
>   missing an input or output annotation.

Any guidance on how to overcome this error.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if this is related to [issue 173](https://github.com/n0mer/gradle-git-properties/issues/173) (Support Gradle 7):

> 2.2.4 seems to be jdk 16 related. When using jdk 15 it works.
>
> v2.3.1 has been published (and seems to be working).

So check which [version of `gradle-git-properties`](https://github.com/n0mer/gradle-git-properties/releases) you are using.

The [OP vamsh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19483562/vamsh) confirms in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73541172/com-gorylenko-generategitpropertiestask-property-gitproperties-is-missing-an/73542557#comment129874091_73542557):

> From Gradle 7.x, I reverted to Gradle 6.x to make it compatible with "`com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties`" version "`2.0.0`", and it's working.

Comment: from `gradle 7.x` i reverted to `gradle 6.x` to make it compatible with `"com.gorylenko.gradle-git-properties" version "2.0.0"`and it's working

Comment: @Vamsh Thank you for your feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.